# WSDL import: Unexpected <xsd:sequence> appears at line

Tags: xml, wsdl, specifications, complextype

I have a large wsdl file and wdsl import gives an error in this part of code. Is there any sintax error for xml specifications? If I delete the line with tag , the error no longer appears.

```
<xsd:complexType name="...">
        <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Item" type="tns:.."/>
        </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `xsd:sequence` should come before `xsd:attribute`:

```
<xsd:complexType name="...">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Item" type="tns:.."/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```